# How to get Zend Route to use a different module depending on the domain name

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I'd like to set up multiple domain names to use the same framework, but I can't seem to get zend's router to bend to my will.

There are plenty of examples using subdomains, but trying to make them work for an entire domain doesn't seem to work as I would expect it to.

Here's the closest I've come, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
resources.router.routes.mysite.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.mysite.route = "www.mysite.com"
resources.router.routes.mysite.defaults.module = "mysite"

resources.router.routes.mysite1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.mysite1.route = "www.mysite1.com"
resources.router.routes.mysite1.defaults.module = "mysite1"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is the module not being set? Recall that the docs recommend chaining a path route to the hostname route. Perhaps the absence of chaining is allowing the module to be set someplace else? Just thinking out loud...

Comment: That's correct, the module is not being set -- it's simply defaulting to the controllers in the "non-moduled" /application/controllers directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon [this Nabble thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/hostname-route-chain-in-application-ini-td661468.html), it looks like you need to add a path route and then chain that path route to your hostname routes.

So perhaps something like:

```
; abstract routes to be used in chaining
resources.router.routes.plain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.plain.abstract = true
resources.router.routes.plain.route = "/:controller/:action"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.action = "index"

resources.router.routes.mysite.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.mysite.abstract = true
resources.router.routes.mysite.route = "www.mysite.com"
resources.router.routes.mysite.defaults.module = "mysite"

resources.router.routes.mysite1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.mysite1.abstract = true
resources.router.routes.mysite1.route = "www.mysite1.com"
resources.router.routes.mysite1.defaults.module = "mysite1"

; now the actual (non-abstract) routes are chains of the abstract ones
resources.router.routes.mysite-plain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain"
resources.router.routes.mysite-plain.chain = "mysite,plain"

resources.router.routes.mysite1-plain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain"
resources.router.routes.mysite1-plain.chain = "mysite1,plain"
```

Actually, we could probably collapse the two abstract mysiteX routes into a single abstract route using a placeholder like `:site` to stand in for the `mysiteX` value and set some requirements/defaults on those, but I think this conveys the idea.

Not tested - actually I have never played with chained routes before - but it seems that something like this is required to make the hostname routing work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This was exactly it except for one thing: `mysite plain` needs to be comma separated like `mysite, plain`. also, don't forget to register the modules first `resources.modules[] = "mysite"`

Comment: Great, glad it helped. For completeness, I'll update the answer body to include your corrections/notes. Cheers!

Comment: For some reason this method fails as soon as you add additional parameters, and falls back to the default module.. example:
`www.mysite.com/index/index` goes to the mysite module... but `www.mysite.com/index/index/p/2` goes to the default module.

Comment: I suppose that's because our `plain` route only covers routes of the form `/:controller/:action`. I guess we have to define additional routes and chain them all in. Once we start getting into the cross-product of all combinations, it makes sense to consider condensing our hostname routes into a single one using a pattern. Then there will be fewer combinations to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by actually using different configuration files based on the current value of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, which is configured by the web server.  (`HTTP_HOST` is the one sent by the client.)

You could probably do the same thing in a single file by using [INI file sections and inheritance](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html).